Why isn't every subspace of $\mathbb R$ a linearly ordered topological space (LOTS)?
(Asking the rhetorical question to provide a reference to begin building up GO-space theory on π-Base.)
The real numbers are a linearlly ordered topological space, generated by the subbasis of rays $\{(\leftarrow,x):x\in\mathbb R\}\cup\{(x,\rightarrow):x\in\mathbb R\}$.
But I understand that doesn't mean that every subspace $S\subseteq\mathbb R$ of reals has such a topology, even though it would be generated by the subbasis $\{(\leftarrow,x)\cap S:x\in\mathbb R\}\cup\{(x,\rightarrow)\cap S:x\in\mathbb R\}$. How can that be?

Is the question purely rhetorical and you’re going to answer it yourself? Because obviously this is just because $x$ doesn’t have to be in $S$?

Every subset of the reals has such a linearly ordered topology - whether or not the topology is natural is a different point entirely.

Of course every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is linearly ordered, and so it does induce the order topology. So if I understand your question correctly, you ask why the order topology doesn't coincide with the subspace topology.
Consider $S=[0,1)\cup \{2\}$. The subspace topology of this space is disconnected. However, if we treat it as linearly ordered set, then there is no real difference between $1$ and $2$, and in fact topology induced by the ordering is homeomorphic to the standard $[0,1]$. Cleary these two are not only different, but even not homeomorphic.
So what is the true reason behind this phenomenom? The core issue is that given $x\in\mathbb{R}$, the $(x,\to)\cap S$ set is not necessarily equal to $(s,\to)$ for some $s\in S$. In the example above consider what happens when $x=1.5$. The same goes for the other direction.
EDIT: Note that the example above does in fact arise as order topology for some ordering. In fact it is homeomorphic to $\{-1\}\cup [0,1)$, and for this space the order topology and subspace topology coincide.
However, we can slightly modify this example to obtain something that doesn't arise from any ordering. Consider $S=(0,1)\cup\{2\}$. I leave as an exercise that this space does not arise as order topology.

Thanks - of course this only shows that the order induced by inclusion does not yield the subspace topology; it's possible that the subspace is still a LOTS under a different ordering.

@StevenClontz I've updated the answer.

First consider the discrete subspace $\{-1\}\cup\{1/n:n\in\mathbb Z^+\}$. This space is a LOTS, as it is a copy of the LOTS $\mathbb Z$ (any bijection will work). But the ordering induced as a subset of $\mathbb R$ would instead be a copy of a converging sequence: there is no set that contains just $-1$ of the form $(\leftarrow,x)$ for $x\in\{-1\}\cup\{1/n:n\in\mathbb Z^+\}$, and no set of the form $(x,\rightarrow)$ contains $-1$ at all, showing that $-1$ is not isolated in the order topology induced by the usual ordering.
So this shows that a subspace of a LOTS may be a LOTS, but perhaps it may require a different ordering. However, the subspace $Y=(0,1)\cup\{2\}$ will demonstrate that a subspace of a LOTS may not be a LOTS at all.
To see this, choose an order $\prec$ on $Y$. If it induced the topology on $Y$, we'd have either $\{2\}=(a,b)_\prec$, $\{2\}=(a,\rightarrow)_\prec$, or $\{2\}=(\leftarrow,b)_\prec$ for points $a,b\in(0,1)$. In the first two cases (the third would follow similarly), we have $(a,2)_\prec=\emptyset$, and thus $Y=(\leftarrow,a]_\prec\cup[2,\rightarrow)_\prec$. This is a disconnection, so we have $(0,1)=(\leftarrow,a]_\prec$ (and $\{2\}=[2,\rightarrow)_\prec$). But then we have a maximum $a$ of a LOTS $(\leftarrow,a]_\prec$ as a cut point, since $(0,1)\setminus\{a\}=(0,a)\cup(a,1)$ is disconnected. This contradicts the following lemma:
Lemma: The cut points of a connected LOTS are exactly the points which are not a maximum or minimum.
Proof: Given a point $x\in L$ which is not the maximum nor minimum of $L$, the sets $(\leftarrow,x),(x,\rightarrow)$ disconnect $L\setminus\{x\}$, showing $x$ is a cut point.
A LOTS is connected iff it is a linear continuum: it has the least upper bound property and is order-dense. The removal of any single point does not affect the order-dense property. Furthermore, the removal of the maximum $m$ does not affect the least upper bound property: given a nonempty subset $S\subseteq L\setminus\{m\}$ with an upper bound $b\in L\setminus\{m\}$, the least upper bound property of $L$ shows there exists a least upper bound $l\leq b<m$ for $S$, and it follows $l\in L\setminus\{m\}$. A similar argument (noting that the least upper bound property implies the greatest lower bound property) follows for the minimum. Therefore the removal of a maximum or a minimum cannot disconnect a LOTS.

Subspace usually means subset with the subspace topology. But in the first paragraph: "the ordering induced as a subspace of R", you are not talking about the subspace topology, right?  Maybe you meant the order topology induced by the restriction of the order of $\mathbb R$ to that particular subset?

In the last paragraph, "dense-in-itself", which is a topological property (= no isolated points) is not what is needed.  For example, $[0,1]\cup[2,3]$ has the least upper bound property and is dense-in-itself, but not connected. It should be replaced by "order-dense" (= for every $x<y$, there is a $z$ with $x<z<y$), which is a purely order theoretic property.

I've (perhaps) addressed both of those points, thanks PatrickR.
